# C# - Numbering lines in richTextBox Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms, lines

got a problem that can't deal with. 
I'm trying to number all lines in richTextBox, program does work, but it crashes when I click on my numbering button.
Can anyone explain me please why?

Code:

```
public string temp = null;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<richTextBox1.Lines.Length+1;i++)
    {
         temp = richTextBox1.Lines[i];
         richTextBox1.Lines[i] = i + ": " + temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's because you are exceeding the length of richTextBox1.Lines capacity. So in the last iteration of your loop you will get index out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array exposed by the `Lines` property is zero based. You will want to change your `for` loop declaration to this:

```
for (i=0;i<richTextBox1.Lines.Length;i++)
```

As your code looks now you will try to access elements in the array that are out of bounds (as well as missing the first line).